# React: Function components cannot be given refs when displaying a modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

The modal is rendered under the hashRouter in App.js. The modal is shown when its state isOpen is true.

I'm given this error when trying to display a Modal with react redux.

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `TrapFocus`.
    in ConnectFunction (at Modal.js:41)
    in TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Modal) (at Modal.js:35)
    in Modal (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by WithStyles(undefined))
    in WithStyles(undefined) (at App.js:46)
    in ThemeProvider (at App.js:24)
    in App (created by WithStyles(App))
    in WithStyles(App) (at src/index.js:13)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:12)
```

This is my code:

Modal.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { compose } from "redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Modal as MaterialModal } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { closeModal } from "../store/actions/actions-ui";
import BasicModal from "./Modals/BasicModal";

const ModalTypes = {
    BasicModal,
};

const styles = {
    modal: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
};

class Modal extends Component {
    handleCloseModal = () => {
        const { dispatch, shouldCloseOnBackgroundTouch } = this.props;
        if (shouldCloseOnBackgroundTouch) dispatch(closeModal());
    };

    render() {
        const { modalType, data, isOpen, classes } = this.props;
        if (!modalType) {
            return null;
        }
        const ModalToRender = ModalTypes[modalType];
        return (
            <MaterialModal
                disableAutoFocus
                className={classes.modal}
                open={isOpen}
                onClose={this.handleCloseModal}
            >
                <ModalToRender {...data} />
            </MaterialModal>
        );
    }
}

Modal.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    modalType: PropTypes.string,
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
    data: PropTypes.object,
    shouldCloseOnBackgroundTouch: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    classes: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
};

Modal.defaultProps = {
    data: {},
    modalType: "",
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isOpen: state.ui.modalState.isOpen,
    shouldCloseOnBackgroundTouch: state.ui.modalState.shouldCloseOnBackgroundTouch,
    modalType: state.ui.modalState.modalType,
    data: state.ui.modalState.data,
});

export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Modal);
```

BasicModal.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import If from "../__helpers__/If";
import { closeModal } from "../../store/actions/actions-ui";

class BasicModal extends Component {
    handleClose = () => {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(closeModal());
    };

    render() {
        const { title, text, extraBtnText, extraBtnAction } = this.props;
        return (
            <Paper>
                <If truthy={title}>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4">
                        {title}
                    </Typography>
                </If>
                <If truthy={text}>
                    <Typography gutterBottom vairant="body2">
                        {text}
                    </Typography>
                </If>

                <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
                <If truthy={extraBtnAction && extraBtnText}>
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => {
                            extraBtnAction();
                            this.handleClose();
                        }}
                    >
                        {extraBtnText}
                    </Button>
                </If>
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}

BasicModal.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    extraBtnText: PropTypes.string,
    extraBtnAction: PropTypes.func,
};

export default connect()(BasicModal);
```

I'm guessing that the issue lies with me trying to render a component like this:

```
<ModalToRender {...data} />
```

But I can't seem to understand what is wrong with it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [forwardRef option in connect()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#forwardref-boolean) for the component (e.g. `BasicModal`) that is wrapped by Material-UI's `Modal`.

Example:

```
export default connect(null, null, null, {forwardRef: true})(BasicModal);
```

[Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) provide access to the DOM node for a React element.  Material-UI's `TrapFocus` (which is used by `Modal`) [uses a ref on the child](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/TrapFocus.js#L125) passed to `Modal` to manage focus aspects.

In your case, the child passed to `Modal` is the wrapper component returned by `connect()(BasicModal)`. That wrapper component is, by default, a function component and function components cannot accept refs except by being wrapped by [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

The `forwardRef` option of `connect` causes it to wrap the function component using `React.forwardRef` so that it can successfully accept a ref which it passes along to the wrapped component (`BasicModal` in your case).

Comment: That solved it,thanks! Care to explain what forwardRef is used for?

Comment: I've added some explanation.