# I have a NON-functional component and still have this error: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail

Tags: reactjs

I have a component nested into another component. I used this approach to call the child component's function and it worked well. But here it's not working although I use the same approach:

```
class MainForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.subFormRef = React.createRef();
    }
    render(){
      return <div><SubForm ref={this.subFormRef} /></div>
}
}

class SubForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    methodToBeCalled = ()=>{
      return true;
    }
    render(){       
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        ) 
    }
}
```

UPD. I figured it out. It turned out the "wrong" component was connected to Redux and it caused the problem. I found the solution here: [React: Function components cannot be given refs when displaying a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097791/react-function-components-cannot-be-given-refs-when-displaying-a-modal)

Comment: What version of React is this code running on? Is this a web project or a React Native project or something else? Can you provide a JSFiddle that demonstrates this error?

Comment: All the code snippets are working with the same version of React, they are part of the same project. One works, another doesn't. React 16.11.0. Not sure about jsfiddle, the code is pretty specific, will be hard to extract.

Comment: I've made the [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h1uwbn) for you. Everything works fine there, so the problem probably is in the code you have not shared.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution, please see the update.